# Extraer el label del nombre de una variable en R

Tags: r, variables, diccionarios, label

Estoy usando una BDD. sav en R y quiero extraer el label/etiqueta del nombre de las variable para realizar un diccionario de datos.

Este es un pequeño ejemplo, el nombre de la variable es p01 y el label es Persona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero generar una columna con el nombre de la variable (p01) y en otra la columna con el lavel (Persona).

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a el `label` de una columna, podemos usar `attr()`, por ejemplo:

```
# Para configurar la etiqueta
attr(mtcars$mpg, "label") <-  "millas por galón"

# Revisamos como se ve
View(mtcars)

# Para leer la etiqueta
etiqueta <- attr(mtcars$mpg, "label")
```